# jQuery map based on attribute value and sort

Tags: jquery, sorting

I am trying to sort foo divs based on arr order:

```
 var arr = [11,33,6,44]

 var parent = $('.parent')

var items = parent.children('.foo')

 <div class="parent">
    <div class="foo" data-media-id="6"></div>
    <div class="foo" data-media-id="11"></div>
    <div class="foo" data-media-id="33"></div>
    <div class="foo" data-media-id="44"></div>
 </div>

 parent.append($.map(arr, function(v) {
    return items.attr('data-media-id="'+v+'"');
 }));
```

If there is more efficient way, I would like to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) sets or returns the value of an attribute so this won't help you in this case.

Instead you want [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) which selects all elements of a collection that match a given selector or pass the function's test. Combine this with an [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) (`'[data-media-id="..."]'`) and you're almost done.

The last step is to fix the markup, so `div.parent` is an actual parent of the `.foo` elements

```js
var arr = [11, 33, 6, 44]

var parent = $('.parent')
var items = parent.children('.foo')

parent.append($.map(arr, function(v) {
  return items.filter('[data-media-id="' + v + '"]');
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="foo" data-media-id="6">6</div>
  <div class="foo" data-media-id="11">11</div>
  <div class="foo" data-media-id="33">33</div>
  <div class="foo" data-media-id="44">44</div>
</div>
```